# docker service create interactive mode

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-swarm

My Dockerfile looks as below

```
FROM base-rpi:latest 
USER root
WORKDIR /Pwr/murata/test 
RUN  make
CMD ["./murata_tcp_test"]
```

Docker build

`docker build --no-cache --rm -t m-docker .`

When I run docker as below :

```
docker run  -it --rm --name m-docker m-docker
```

it shows me interactive console and allows me to select the options

```
****** Test application **********
Press 1 for connect
Press 2 for add a node
Press 0 for exit
Enter choice
******************************************
```

But in swarm mode when I do

```
docker service create --name m-docker  m-docker:latest
```

it is unable to start docker container with below message

```
overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks
1/1: preparing [=================================>                 ]
verify: Detected task failure
```

Docker service logs show that container is started/stopped repeatedly

```
docker service logs m-docker -f


m-docker.1.9gwwzx4r0isn@raspberrypi    | ****** Test application **********
m-docker.1.9gwwzx4r0isn@raspberrypi    | Press 1 for connect
m-docker.1.9gwwzx4r0isn@raspberrypi    | Press 2 for add a node
m-docker.1.kpg4fxom4uyw@raspberrypi    | ****** Test application **********
m-docker.1.kpg4fxom4uyw@raspberrypi    | Press 1 for connect
m-docker.1.kpg4fxom4uyw@raspberrypi    | Press 2 for add a node
m-docker.1.9gwwzx4r0isn@raspberrypi    | Press 0 for exit
m-docker.1.9gwwzx4r0isn@raspberrypi    | Enter choice
m-docker.1.kpg4fxom4uyw@raspberrypi    | Press 0 for exit
m-docker.1.kpg4fxom4uyw@raspberrypi    | Enter choice
m-docker.1.tk676t1aabmh@raspberrypi    | ****** Test application **********
```

How to run docker service create in interactive mode . I referred the docker service create documentation but it doesnot provide any option to run in interactive mode

Answer (score 1):

That because of `swarm`, it runs container by default in detach mode, so no tty will be allocated to interact with container.

Did you tried to run with

```
docker service create --name m-docker --tty   m-docker:latest
```

This will allocate pseudo-TTY

```
--tty , -t      API 1.25+   Allocate a pseudo-TTY
```

[service_create](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With the --tty command docker service is started but it is not showing the options in the console after service is started. However, I can see these options in the docker service logs ... command

Comment: Yes this is expected in case of docker swarm because it run the container in the background, if you run `docker run  -d --rm --name m-docker m-docker` then you will also not able to interact.

Comment: Is there no way to run the docker service interactively. 1) If I do docker run on swarm mode the container will be attached to one host

Comment: I did not find a way in the documentation but due to run in background  mode it will not interact as you expect.